# Запись в конец файла

Tags: java, scanner

Есть файл, и там есть некоторые строки, мне нужно через Java **дописать** в конец файла еще строку *(или строки)*. Вот мой метод который это должен был реализовать реализует:

```
public void Write() throws FileNotFoundException {
    // Метод для записи в файл
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(Kfile);
    Scanner InputFile = new Scanner(System.in);
    pw.println(InputFile.nextLine());
    pw.close();
}
```

Но этот вводимый пользователем текст полностью заменяет содержимое файла

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо открыть файл в режиме дозаписи

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(pathToFile, true));
```

Answer (score 3):

Используйте FileWriter с конструктором `FileWriter(File file, boolean append)`. `append` указывает на то, дописывать данные в конец файла(true) или нет(false)

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName, true);
...
String s = "qwe";
fw.write(s, 0, s.length());
fw.close();
```

P.s. лучше обернуть это в BufferedWriter или PrintWriter